# included a plugin in my emberjs project, shows defined in browser, but is not defined when I call it in the app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

inside app/helpers/showdown.js

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper("markdown", function(input) {
    var showdown = new Showdown.converter();
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(showdown.makeHtml(input));
});
```

I get Showdown is not defined.

I thought maybe this had something to do with jslint not allowing global variables that are undefined, so I added it to my jslintrc

```
"globals": {
  "moment": true,
  "Emberfront": true,
  "jQuery": true,
  "Ember": true,
  "Showdown": true,
  "Handlebars": true,
  "DS": true
}
```

If I put this in my index.html it works fine

```
<script>
Ember.Handlebars.helper("markdown", function(input) {
    var showdown = new Showdown.converter();
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(showdown.makeHtml(input));
});
</script>
```

I know I've required the helpers/showdown.js correctly because my moment.js is required the same way and it works fine.

in app.js

```
require('scripts/helpers/*');
require('scripts/controllers/*');
require('scripts/store');
require('scripts/models/*');
require('scripts/routes/*');
require('scripts/views/*');
require('scripts/router');
```

here's a pic of the console

[image]

and a link if you can't see it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCeUH.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Showdown but create an instance before initializing the ember app, see: https://github.com/pixelhandler/blog/blob/8be3d8b93677a5e91104f1e228b6781de5329371/client/app/assets/index.html#L23-L24

And use that instance in the Handlebars helper here: https://github.com/pixelhandler/blog/blob/8be3d8b93677a5e91104f1e228b6781de5329371/client/app/helpers/format-markdown.js#L3-L7

Comment: Works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this inside the ember app rather than just creating a global outside of ember.

Comment: tack it onto your Ember App, `App = Ember.Application.create({showdown:new Showdown.converter()})`, then from the helper grab it off the app.